# Trying to install a node on Google Cloud platform, and use that node in a function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorize.net

I am trying to run `npm install authorizenet` and use that node in a function, but Google Cloud is saying that "File authorizenet.js that is expected to define function doesn't exist." after I run the command in the command-line. I am trying to create a function to charge a credit card for a donation, and I'm just lost. any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have uploaded my code to Github: https://github.com/IHS5452/gCloud-contents

Comment: Can you provide as much detail as possible.    Can you describe exactly the command you are running and the files you are supplying?  As a quick guess, are you providing a package.json which lists "authorizenet" as a dependency to your require() in your JavaScript source code?

Comment: I uploaded my code to github: https://github.com/IHS5452/gCloud-contents

Comment: I am doing the following:
1) running 'npm install authorize.net' in the console. It succeeds.
2) uploading the files I uploaded on GitHub. it succeeds.
3) When it compiles, it fails.

Comment: Are you using Authorizenet API https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html running in a GCP instance? I'm trying to identify the GCP Product you are using

Comment: I am. I'm using it with node.js

Comment: I am using it as a cloud function

Comment: I figured it out. I was calling authroizenet as a file on the server...